# Magento 2.4.1 installation composer or Archive

Tags: magento2.4.1

I have to install Magento 2.4.1 for the Live website. There are many options are available for Magento 2.4.1 installation.

1. Composer
2. Git
3. Archive

Can someone tell me which method should I prefer and best? Please give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the table in this site https://magento.com/tech-resources/download
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the composer approach (for the reasons referred also by the official documentation) on all your environments (not only production).

In addition to this, I suggest you also manage all your 3rd party integrations or custom code integrations with composer as well. This will grant you the possibility to upgrade your modules' code really easy (both Magento core and custom code/ 3rd party).

Answer (score 0):

go with `composer` as it **`reduces the code debt`**

Besides this you can easily get, add, remove a package (extension) to your codebase with the help of few commands. Dev Life gets easier with this approach.

Regarding the other options,

**Git**  - one can use this if they plan to contribute to Magento Open source and its not ideal for production instance. Of course, you must have your own repo for your production instance to deploy and build.

**Archives** - One can use this, to quickly setup Magento for a trial. Its up to one whether to use this approach to setup a production instance